# How do you prove that only two 4-regular graphs on 7 vertices exist? (Up to isomorphism)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I am wondering how to determine all graphs that are 4-regular and have 7 vertices. I just attempted to draw different graphs until I found two, then verified online that those are indeed the (only) two graphs that fit the requirement.
My two questions are, how, if there is a way, can I determine those two graphs originally without just using guess-and-check, and most importantly how do I go about proving that no other graph works?
Would I have to prove that any adjacency matrix that is 4-regular is just a permutation of the two I already have? I don't quite know where to start.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The complement of $4$-regular graph on $7$ vertices is $2$-regular. Any $2$-regular graph is sum of disjoint cycles. Since every cycle has to have at least three vertices, $3+4$ and $7$ are the only options for these cycles, and they correspond to two $4$-regular graphs.